# XPath Script does not work for input one, but works perfectly fine for input two

Tags: xml, linux, bash, xpath, xmllint

Okay, I'm not really sure how to describe my problem, basically I've got a XML file I'm trying to fetch some information by searching the XML file for a node containing a string.

My problem is that the following script does the job if I only include the `<table>` tag I'm interested in instead of the whole XML file. That is input two as I call it, which works fine.

But it does not work if I use the whole XML file, here is the script:
`(tidy -asxml input.xml | xmllint --xpath 'descendant-or-self::*[starts-with(text(), "Aktiv tid:")]/following-sibling::*/text()' -) 2>/dev/null`

And here is the input one XML file (complete XML file):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>SpeedTouch - Bredbandsanslutning</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript">var g_navitem = -1;</script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> var g_focus = -1;</script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/util.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css">
</head>
<body onLoad="setFocus();" height="100%" style="margin:0px">
  <noscript>
    <h1>Thomson - SpeedTouch</h1>
    <h4>To view the Web interface of your device, JavaScript must be supported and enabled on your browser! <br><br>Aktivera skriptstöd och uppdatera webbläsaren.</h4>
  </noscript>
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="background-color:white" height="100%">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:15px;" class="Product">THOMSON&nbsp;ST780</td><td align="right" style="padding:5px 15px 0px 0px;"><a href="http://www.thomson-broadband.com"><img src="/images/Thomson.gif" border="0" width="109" height="50" alt="THOMSON logo"></a></td>
          </tr>      
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
              <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tr style="background-image:url(/images/bar.gif)">
                  <td width="20%"></td>
                  <td width="10" align="left"></td>
                  <td width="10"><img src="/images/barend_left.gif"></td>
                  <td><img width="100%" height="10" src="/images/spacer_white.gif"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-image:url(/images/bar.gif)">
                  <td align="right"><img width="100%" height="10" src="/images/spacer_white.gif"></td>
                  <td width="10"><img src="/images/barend_right.gif"></td>
                  <td colspan="2"></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="padding-right:15px"><form name="langSelect" action="/cgi/language.cgi" method=post><span class="langSelect"><input type="hidden" name=6 value="en">
<a href="" onClick="setLanguage('en');submitForm(document.langSelect,0);return false;" title="English">en</a>&nbsp;
<strong>sv</strong>&nbsp;</span></form></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" border="0" width="1" height="10" alt=""><br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" style="padding-top:15px;padding-left:15px;">
        <script type="text/javascript">writeMenu();</script>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" style="background:url(/images/wave.gif) no-repeat top center;height:340px">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin-top:15px">
          <script type="text/javascript">writeNavBar();</script>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table width="700" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                   <script type="text/javascript">pm_write_messages();</script>


<div class='contentcontainer'>
<hr>
<div class='contentitem'>
<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr><td class='icon' valign='top' width='100px'><img src='/images/cplngrxl.gif' alt='Fysisk anslutning OK'></td>
<td class='data' valign='top'><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td align='left'><span class='itemtitle'>DSL-anslutning</span></td><td align='right'></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan='2'><br><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%'><tr><td width='40' valign='top'><img src='/images/bull__md.gif' alt=''></td><td valign='top'>
<span class='blocktitle'><a href="javascript:GoAndRemember('/cgi/b/dsl/ov/', '')">Visa mer...</a></span><br>
<table width='100%' class='datatable' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr><td></td><td width='30px'></td><td width='220px'></td><td width='50px'></td></tr>
<tr><td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td></tr>
<tr><td width='170'>Aktiv tid:</td><td colspan='3'>1 dag, 21:44:06</td></tr>
<tr><td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td></tr>
<tr><td width='170'>Bandbredd (upp/ned) [kbps/kbps]:</td><td colspan='3'>1.058 / 21.373</td></tr>
<tr><td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td></tr>
<tr><td width='170'>Överförda data (skickade/mottagna) [GB/GB]:</td><td colspan='3'>1,97 / 45,23</td></tr>
</table>
</td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div>
<hr>
<div class='contentitem'>
<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr><td class='icon' valign='top' width='100px'><img src='/images/cintgrxl.gif' alt='Internetanslutning OK'></td>
<td class='data' valign='top'><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td align='left'><span class='itemtitle'>Internet</span></td><td align='right'></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan='2'><br><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%'><tr><td width='40' valign='top'><img src='/images/bull__md.gif' alt=''></td><td valign='top'>
<span class='blocktitle'><a href="javascript:GoAndRemember('/cgi/b/is/_ethoa_/ov/', 'name=Internet')">Visa mer...</a></span><br>
<table width='100%' class='datatable' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr><td></td><td width='30px'></td><td width='220px'></td><td width='50px'></td></tr>
<tr><td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td></tr>
<tr><td width='170'>Typ:</td><td colspan='3'>ETHoA</td></tr>
<tr><td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td></tr>
<tr><td width='170'>Aktiv tid:</td><td colspan='3'>1 dag, 21:44:04</td></tr>
<tr><td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td></tr>
<tr><td width='170'>IP-adress:</td><td colspan='3'>x.x.x.x</td></tr>
<tr><td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td></tr>
<tr><td width='170'>Överförda data (skickade/mottagna) [GB/GB]:</td><td colspan='3'>1,56 / 39,92</td></tr>
</table>
</td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div>
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'>generateTasks()</script>
</div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the input two XML file:

```
<hr>
<div class='contentitem'>
<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr><td class='icon' valign='top' width='100px'><img src='/images/cplngrxl.gif' alt='Fysisk anslutning OK'></td>
<td class='data' valign='top'><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td align='left'><span class='itemtitle'>DSL-anslutning</span></td><td align='right'></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan='2'><br><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%'><tr><td width='40' valign='top'><img src='/images/bull__md.gif' alt=''></td><td valign='top'>
<span class='blocktitle'><a href="javascript:GoAndRemember('/cgi/b/dsl/ov/', '')">Visa mer...</a></span><br>
<table width='100%' class='datatable' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr><td></td><td width='30px'></td><td width='220px'></td><td width='50px'></td></tr>
<tr><td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td></tr>
<tr><td width='170'>Aktiv tid:</td><td colspan='3'>1 dag, 21:44:06</td></tr>
<tr><td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td></tr>
<tr><td width='170'>Bandbredd (upp/ned) [kbps/kbps]:</td><td colspan='3'>1.058 / 21.373</td></tr>
<tr><td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td></tr>
<tr><td width='170'>Överförda data (skickade/mottagna) [GB/GB]:</td><td colspan='3'>1,97 / 45,23</td></tr>
</table>
</td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div>
<hr>
<div class='contentitem'>
<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr><td class='icon' valign='top' width='100px'><img src='/images/cintgrxl.gif' alt='Internetanslutning OK'></td>
<td class='data' valign='top'><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td align='left'><span class='itemtitle'>Internet</span></td><td align='right'></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan='2'><br><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%'><tr><td width='40' valign='top'><img src='/images/bull__md.gif' alt=''></td><td valign='top'>
<span class='blocktitle'><a href="javascript:GoAndRemember('/cgi/b/is/_ethoa_/ov/', 'name=Internet')">Visa mer...</a></span><br>
<table width='100%' class='datatable' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr><td></td><td width='30px'></td><td width='220px'></td><td width='50px'></td></tr>
<tr><td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td></tr>
<tr><td width='170'>Typ:</td><td colspan='3'>ETHoA</td></tr>
<tr><td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td></tr>
<tr><td width='170'>Aktiv tid:</td><td colspan='3'>1 dag, 21:44:04</td></tr>
<tr><td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td></tr>
<tr><td width='170'>IP-adress:</td><td colspan='3'>x.x.x.x</td></tr>
<tr><td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td></tr>
<tr><td width='170'>Överförda data (skickade/mottagna) [GB/GB]:</td><td colspan='3'>1,56 / 39,92</td></tr>
</table>
</td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div>
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'>generateTasks()</script>
</div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

So for some reason if I remove everything before and including this line:

> `<div class='contentcontainer'>`

the script works fine.

This seems very strange to me, but seems like a very basic problem.

So my question is how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you tried to run only the first part of your pipeline to inspect its output, you would notice that

```
tidy -asxml input.xml
```

returns no data for the given file.

This is due to the spurious `</form>` (as the document contains only a single `<form>` but two `</form>`s) -- which HTMLTidy **tells you explicitly in its message written to stderr**, should you choose to read it.

---

In short: While Tidy can clean up documents with *warnings*, any document with *errors* needs to be repaired before it can be processed.

Comment: Thank you, I can't do this manually because the XML file will be downloaded from the web (from my router's homepage), and then processed automatically. This will happen every five minute, so doing it manually would be very ineffective.

Comment: Any fix is going to necessarily be some level of ugly hack. If you just want something that works for now, and won't necessarily work when your router's firmware is next revved, using `sed` to delete the second `</form>` would do the trick.

Comment: ...you might also try using BeautifulSoup, to see if it does a better job than Tidy of coping with that particular flavor of invalid input.

Comment: I tried to delete it manually and the script didn't give me any output.

Comment: Worked fine for me, but obviously I'm not running the exact same versions of Tidy and friends as you are. Have you tried **actually reading the error messages** from Tidy?

Comment: Yes, it didn't give me any errors, I downloaded the latest version of tidy about an hour or two ago.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/3632c3ec0b9b5c730215 -- you can check this out with git and run the script yourself.

Comment: Thanks for providing the script, it did give me that error, but when I removed the </form> it did not. Although my main problem is still there, the second part of the script (i.e ` | xmllint --xpath 'descendant-or-self::*[starts-with(text(), "Aktiv tid:")]/following-sibling::*/text()' -)` did not work, even though I fixed the error.

Comment: If perhaps instead of only looking at whether you get output or not you instead looked at the messages printed to stderr, there'd be less time wasted on both of our parts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61227/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-linus).

Comment: Sorry, I missed them due to the `2>/dev/null` part afterwards, however, looking at the errors for both of the XML input files in my question, there were a lot more errors on input two. Which is due I cut the document without bothering to fix any errors. What am I missing?

Comment: Ignore the warnings and look only at the things that say `Error:`.